# Как удалить отренедереный компонент в React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

У меня выводятся карточки с покемонами при клике на которые мне показывает больше информации о покемоне. У меня всё работает только больше информации о покемоне выводится один под другим а мне нужно чтобы предыдущий исчезал  и новый появлялся. Как я могу удалить уже отрендеренжий компонент с  детальной информацией и показать новый при новом клике.

```
class PokemonListCard extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pokemonImgTemplate: "https://pokeres.bastionbot.org/images/pokemon/{id}.png",
            pokemonList: [],
            currentPage: 0,
            apiTemplateUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=currentPage&limit=12",
            pokemonValue: []
        }   
        this.loadMore();
    }

    loadMore=(newCurrentPage)=>{
        this.setState({
            currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
        })
        let currentPage = newCurrentPage;
        let num = 12 * currentPage;
        let apiTemplateUrl = this.state.apiTemplateUrl;
        let apiUrl = apiTemplateUrl.replace("currentPage",num);
            fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((listPokemons) => {
                listPokemons.results.forEach((aboutPokemon) => {
                    let aboutPokemonUrl = aboutPokemon.url;
                    fetch(aboutPokemonUrl)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((listEachPokemon) => {
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            pokemonList: [...prevState.pokemonList, listEachPokemon]
                          }))
                    })
                 })
            })
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            DataSource.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
          }

        loadAboutInfo=(pokemonValue,pockemonImg)=>{
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                pokemonValue:[...prevState.pokemonValue, pokemonValue],
                pockemonImg
            }))
        }

    render() {
        return (                    
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="pokemonlist__inner__cards">
                    <div className="pokemonlist__cards">
                        {this.state.pokemonList.map((value,index)=>{
                            let pokemonImgTemplate = this.state.pokemonImgTemplate;
                            let pokemonId = value.id;
                            let pockemonImg = pokemonImgTemplate.replace('{id}',pokemonId);
                            return(
                                <div className="pokemonlist__card" key={index} onClick={()=>this.loadAboutInfo(value,pockemonImg)}>
                                    <PokemonImage 
                                        pockemonImg={pockemonImg}
                                    />
                                    <PokemonName 
                                        pokemonName={value.name}
                                    />
                                    <PokemonTypes 
                                        pokemonTypes={value.types}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <PokemonLoadMore 
                        loadMore={this.loadMore}
                        currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
                    />
                </div>
                <PokemonAbout 
                        pokemonValue={this.state.pokemonValue}
                        pockemonImg={this.state.pockemonImg}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Компонент который выводит карточку с дополнительной информацией

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pokemon__about">
                        {this.props.pokemonValue.map((value,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <div className="pokemon__about__inner" key={index}>
                                    <img src={this.props.pockemonImg} alt=""/>
                                    <h1>{value.name}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Я пробовал сделать с помощью `componentWillUnmount()` но наверное делал неправильно.
Спасибо большое за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Удалять отренедереный компонент не нужно, достаточно вызвать ререндеринг и отрисовать компонент по новой. Предлагаю следующее решение:

Добавляем в стейт выбранного покемона `selectedPokemon`, изначально будет `null`:

```
this.state = {
  selectedPokemon: null,
  // some code here...
}
```

Метод `loadAboutInfo` заменяем на следующий (изменение значения приведет к ререндерингу):

```
onSelectPokemon = (index) => {
  this.setState({ selectedPokemon: index });
}
```

Далее в методе рендеринга добавляем условие, которое будет определять, выбран ли покемон и отображать ли дополнительную информацию по нему:

```
{this.state.pokemonList.map((value,index)=>{
  let pokemonImgTemplate = this.state.pokemonImgTemplate;
  let pokemonId = value.id;
  let pockemonImg = pokemonImgTemplate.replace('{id}',pokemonId);
  return (
    <div className="pokemonlist__card" key={index} onClick={()=>this.onSelectPokemon(index)}>
        <PokemonImage 
          pockemonImg={pockemonImg}
        />
        <PokemonName 
          pokemonName={value.name}
        />
        <PokemonTypes 
          pokemonTypes={value.types}
        />
        {this.state.selectedPokemon === index &&
          <PokemonAbout 
            pokemonValue={value}
            pockemonImg={pockemonImg}
          />
        }
    </div>
  )
})}
```

В грубом примере будет выглядеть как-то так, просто добавлено условие: `this.state.selectedPokemon === index` по которому отображается `PokemonAbout`. Скорее всего придется поправить CSS стили, но это уже не сложно. Думаю, что основная идея понятна.